# What's wrong with my merge sort implementation

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I'm sure I'm making an incredibly silly mistake but I've been at this for hours and I just want my code to sort prettily... Something is going wrong with implementation when odd numbers come into the equation.

Below is my `MergeSplit` method:

```
     static List<Motor> MergeSplit(List<int> ListX)
     {
            int n = ListX.Count;
            if (n <= 1)
                return ListX;

            List<int> left = new List<int>();
            List<int> right = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (i < (n / 2))
                    left.Add(ListX[i]);
                else
                    right.Add(ListX[i]);
            }

            left = MergeSplit(left);
            right = MergeSplit(right);
            return Merge(left, right);

      }
```

And here is the `Merge` method:

```
    static List<int> Merge(List<int> ListX, List<int>  ListY)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        int i = 0;
        while (ListX.Count > i && ListY.Count > i)
        {
            if (ListX[i] > ListY[i])
            {
                result.Add(ListY[i]);
                result.Add(ListX[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(ListX[i]);
                result.Add(ListY[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }

        //If odd, add the rest to the result
        if (ListX.Count > ListY.Count)
            result.Add(ListX[ListX.Count - 1]);
        else if (ListY.Count > ListX.Count)
            result.Add(ListY[ListY.Count - 1]);

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

**Update**

The algorithm just doesnt sort correctly with certain inputs

Comment: But your code will not even compile because you return `return ListX` but return type is `List<Motor>`

Comment: *Something is going wrong* is an absolutely useless problem description. Instead, explain **specifically** what is*going wrong*. What problem are you having?. If you want help, you need to clearly explain the problem and ask a specific question. *Something is going wrong* and *What's wrong?* are not specific in any sense. What is the input you're providing? What output are you getting that does not meet your expectations?

Comment: Wlecome to Stack Overflow! Most of the folks on here will answer questions, but they won't debug your code for you. This question will probably get downvoted and closed. But if you can narrow down the issue, you can edit your question or post another one. Please be sure to take the [tour] and visit [ask]. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Merge routine

You are comparing the left and right and adding them to the list respectively, where you should be comparing the heads, and adding the lowest to the result, and removing that head respectively for the next comparison

This is the pseudo code from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

```
while left is not empty and right is not empty do
    if first(left) ≤ first(right) then
        append first(left) to result
        left := rest(left)
    else
        append first(right) to result
        right := rest(right)
```

You can see why thats important here

[image]

As you can see its actually comparing the first left and first right, then adding them to the result and removing that item from the list. which is vastly different from what you are doing. you either need 2 index variables, or remove the items from the list

```
while (listX.Count > 0 && listY.Count > 0)
   if (listX[0] > listY[0])
   {
      result.Add(listY[0]);
      listY.RemoveAt(0);
   }
   else
   {
      result.Add(listX[0]);
      listX.RemoveAt(0);
   }


if (listX.Count > 0)
   result.AddRange(listX);
else if (listY.Count > 0)
   result.AddRange(listY);
```

Just for fun, i found this was easier to play with queues, they seem to like this sort of thing

```
private static Queue<int> Merge(Queue<int> left, Queue<int> right)
{
   var result = new Queue<int>();

   while (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
      result.Enqueue(left.Peek() > right.Peek() ? right.Dequeue() : left.Dequeue());

   foreach (var item in left)
      result.Enqueue(item);

   foreach (var item in right)
      result.Enqueue(item);

   return result;
}

private static Queue<int> MergeSplit(Queue<int> list)
{
   var n = list.Count;

   if (n <= 1)
      return list;

   var left = new Queue<int>();
   var right = new Queue<int>();

   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (i < n / 2)
         left.Enqueue(list.Dequeue());
      else
         right.Enqueue(list.Dequeue());

   left = MergeSplit(left);
   right = MergeSplit(right);
   return Merge(left, right);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<int> { 8, 7, 6, 4, 43, 23, 435, 76, 7, 7877, 5, 421, 2 };
var results = MergeSplit(new Queue<int>(list));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 23, 43, 76, 421, 435, 7877
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkHS4H)

Comment: Thank you so much! I realise it's bad to ask questions that don't benefit the community, so I really appreciate your help! Very easy to understand - was a basic conceptual mistake. Thanks again! And for the queuing code!